# Connect a Server to Hyper-V-Manager

Tags: credentials, hyper-v, gpo

2 weeks ago I had that issue to, and I solved it by enabling a GPO and adding the FQDN of the server to the server list in the GPO. And that's my problem: I don't know which GPO it was, but I'm pretty sure it was one of the following:

- Allow delegating fresh credentials (Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Credential Delegation)
- Allow delegating fresh credentials with NTLM-only server authentication (Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Credential Delegation)

So I checked the values of the policies on my other computer where I configured it correctly before 2 weeks and copied it to the PC I wanna connect. That means that I enabled this GPO's and fill in the FQDN of the server in the server list of the GPO's (Like that: wsman/pcname or wsman/pcname.domain.com). I run 'gpupdate' as well as I restarted the pc but unfortunatelly it doesn't work.

By the way I can connect to the server via RDP without problems. I ensured that the 'Virtual Maschine Management service' is running, too. Both pc's and the server are in the same domain. I tried the Powershell command 'Enable-PSRemoting' too, and it run without problems. The OS of the system is Hyper-V Server 2016 and the OS of the computers are both Windows 10. Hopefully I didn't forget anything.

I've run out of ideas. Do you have some? And feel free to ask for further information!

Pictures:

[connect to server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q14QL.png)

[hyper-v-manager error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJcZs.png)

[GPO delegating credential (ntlm)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcRQq.png)

[GPO delegating credential (no ntlm)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lejub.png)

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself. For everyone who has the same problem:

Enable the Policy "Encryption Oracle Remediation" and set the Protection Level to "Vulnerable" and klick on "OK".

Enable the Policy "Allow delegating fresh credentials" and add "WSMAN/*" into the server list in the options section of the policy and click on "OK".

Enable the Policy "Allow delegating fresh credentials with NTLM-only server authentication" and add "WSMAN/*" into the server list in the options section of the policy and click on "OK" as well.

After run gpupdate in the console I could connect to my server in Hyper-V-Manager including provide the credentials of the server as shown in picture 1 "connect to server".

Hopefully it will fix your problem, too!

P.S.: The policies can be found under "Local Computer Policy → Computer Configuration → Administrative Templates → System → Credential Delegation"

Best regards